# how to get the index of the first loop for another array jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access the index of the foreach loop to access the second element

```
$.each("input:checkbox[name=city[]]:checked", function (index, item) {
    var category = $('select[name="category[]["' + index + '"]"]').val();
    alert(category);
    var split = category = category.split('_');
    var category = split[0];
    if (category == "0") {
        alert('Please select hotel category');
        validate = "false";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        validate = "true";
    }
});
```

This is my html

```
<select name="category[]" 
         id="webmenus_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>"      
         onchange="showValue(this.value)"
 >
     <option value="0" selected="selected" title="Please select hotel category"></option>
     <option value="5_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/5star.png"></option>
     <option value="4_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/4star.png"></option>
     <option value="3_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/3star.png"></option>
     <option value="2_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/2star.png"></option>
     <option value="1_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/1star.png"></option>
</select>
```

But i am getting as undefined.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you get as undefined? Index or category?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is not undefined index, but the redundant double quotes in your selector, try removing them:

```
var category = $('select[name="category[][' + index + ']"]').val();
```

With your original syntax the selector would look like `select[name="category[]["0"]"]`, which is not valid due to unescaped nested double quotes.

Comment: so what is the correct format. I tried your earlier answer but it is still giving undefined

Comment: what is undefined? show your html, do you have `<select name="category[][0]" ... >`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have many `city[]` checkboxes, each with a corresponding `category[]` select, your code will **not**  give you what you want... `index` in `$.each` refers to the index of the element relative to the selector, not relative to the page. (If I'm wrong in this assumption, please clarify your question, for instance posting your html code too)

A better way to select a related field would be finding a common parent and then searching it for a specific class. For instance, if your markup is like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" />
        ...
        <select name="category[]">...</select>
    </li>
    <li> ... </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

You can query the right `select` using, for instance:

```
$.each("input:checkbox[name=city[]]:checked", function (index, item) {
    var category = $(this).closest("li").find('select[name="category[]"]').val();
    ...
```

Comment: they are not in the ul li, they are in the same div. I tried your code i am still getting undefined when i alert the category value.

Comment: That was just an example. You should adjust it to your specific case. If they are just under the same div, use `closest("div")` (or even `.parent()`) instead of `closest("li")`. See the [docs for closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using foreach loop for both the city and category.

```
 $("input:checkbox[name='city[]']:checked").each(function(j){
                var city=$(this);
                $('select[name="category[]"]').each(function(i){
                    if(i==j){
                        if($(this).val()=="0"){
                            alert("Please select hotel category");
                            city.click();
                            city.attr('checked', true);
                            validate="false";
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            validate="true";
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                if(validate=="false"){
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

thanks all,

Comment: Are you sure your code work for all cases? As I said in my answer, the index in `each` callback is relative to the set of selected elements, not the total number of elements in the page. For instance, if there are 5 checkboxes and 5 selects, but only 3 checkboxes are checked, `j` will be in `[0,1,2]` but `i` will be in `[0,1,2,3,4]`. It's fine if the checked elements are the 3 first (maybe that's how your code work, I don't know), but if you skip one then your code will give incorrect results.